# C - function to search a substring.. need to simplify

Tags: c, string

To begin with, I am a novie in C. So please bear with me.

I am referring a tutorial on pointers, which asked me to write a function to find a substring (and if found, the function should return the location of the substring in the original string).

I wrote the code and it works perfectly, the only problem is its too lengthy and I was wondering, if there was a way I can make it less complex.

Following is the code -

- `*s` - contains the base address of the string,
- `*t` - contains the base address of the substring,
- `num` - contains the number of characters in substring (calculated by using strlen)

> 

```
char *search(char *s, char *t, int num)
{ 
    int i = 0, flag = 0;

    /* increment str1 until first matching character (of substring) is encountered */
    while((*s != *t) && (*s != '\0'))
    {
        s++;
    }

    if(*s == *t)
    {
        /* comparing the str and substr, and incrementing flag.. if flag is incremented num times, the strings match */
        while((*(s+i) == *(t+i)) && (i<num))
        {
            flag++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(flag == num)
        return s;
    else
        /* recursive function - str is incremented by 1, to start new comparison */
        return search((s+1), t, num);
}
```

Any help would be appreaciated. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: in the case of substring  is not found, it is not considered.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot to consider that scenario. Thanks Bluepixy.

Comment: The code has various places undefined behaviour can be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to special-case finding the first character:

```
char * search(char *s, char *t, int num)
{
    while (*s) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (!s[i]) {
                return NULL;
            }

            if (s[i] != t[i]) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == num) {
            return s;
        }

        s++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `if (!s[i]) { return NULL;  }` does not appear to be needed if `num` is `strlen(t)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's alread done quite well, just a few litte things:

```
char * search(char *s, char *t, int num)
{ 
    int i = 0, flag = 0;

    /* increment str1 until first matching character (of substring) is encountered */
    /* It can be written on one line: */
    while((*s != *t) && (*s != '\0')) s++;

    /* comparing the str and substr, and incrementing flag.. if flag is incremented num times, the strings match */
    /* The if is not needed, a for loop is shorter: */
    for(; (*(s+i) == *(t+i)) && (i<num); flag++, i++);

    if(flag == num)
        return s;
    else
        /* recursive function - str is incremented by 1, to start new comparison */
        return search((s+1), t, num);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the strstr() function

```
return strstr(s, t);
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Comment: OP needs to **implement** the function himself/herself. (Also, tutorialspoint contains a lot of misinformation and downright wrong things – don't link to it.)

Comment: Linking to some actual libc implementation of strstr might have been more relevant.

Comment: I am aware of that function, Nick. Thanks for the input though.